# Display JavaScript Date in X axis in hightcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a series consisting of a pair X,Y values. X being a Javascript Date.

When displaying the graph I can't see in the X any reference to those date values. 
How can I display them in the X axys as well as in the tooltips?

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/sqsdf83L/)

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minPadding: 0.05,
            maxPadding: 0.05
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                [new Date(2016,08,28), 29.9],
                [new Date(2016,09,28), 71.5],
                [new Date(2016,10,28), 106.4]
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Date.UTC method.

You can just update this:

```
[new Date(2016,08,28), 29.9]
```

To

```
[Date.UTC(2016,08,28), 29.9]
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/sqsdf83L/1/

(keep in mind, month numbers start at 0 in javascript, not 1, so adjust accordingly)